# Анимация в Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Нужно сделать одновременную анимацию персонажа (Движение (`Transform.posistion`) и махи хвостом (два кадра через `SpriteSheet`). В окне Animation это всё делается одновременно и в итоге получаем что два кадра махи хвостом делаются а потом анимация идет дальше, в движение.

Можно как нибудь их сделать независимыми? Чтобы была анимация махов хвостом и анимация движения, одновременно и независимо друг от друга?

Можно конечно `transform.position` сделать через скриптинг, через вектора, но может можно это сделать именно средствами анимации?

Comment: Точно Animation? Или Animator? А то некоторые путают.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можешь использовать для движений какой нибудь твинер, как например, DoTween. Отдаешь ему вектор конечный куда нужно двинуть объект и за какое время, он будет тебе передвигать, в момент старта движения включить анимацию.

```
transform.DOMove(new Vector3(2,3,4), 1);
```

В анимациях лучше не менять позицию объекта, а что если нужно будет двинуть объект в другую сторону? или чуть дальше, чуть медленнее?

Comment: Но ведь анимация ходьбы, к примеру, это уже само по себе изменение transform.position ног и рук)) Только не относительно пространства, а относительно некой точки самого объекта. Разве нет?))

Comment: Да, можно менять позиции дочерних объектов относительно родительского, но лучше не менять позицию родительского объекта относительно мировых координат. Если посмотреть анимации качественных моделей, то можно заметить что анимация ходьбы играет, но объект стоит на месте. Само движение производится из кода

Comment: Это я знаю) `В анимациях лучше не менять позицию объекта` - просто объект - не значит весь персонаж. Рука, по сути, тоже объект, только в рамках более глобального объекта) ну это я так.....